# How could I abstract away logging details?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, error-logging

I have many places in my code base where I would like to be notified when things are going wrong - pretty common I imagine.  Looking at the following code, how could I re-factor this method to abstract away the email/logging details?  Currently, this is scattered in about 100 places and I really need to do something about it!

```
public bool MethodOne() {
    string message;
    bool success = new Task().Execute();

    message = string.Format( "MethodOne was {0} successful.", 
        success ? "" : "not");

    if( !success )
        SMTP.send( to, from, message );

    System.Diagnostic.EventLog.WriteEntry( executingAssembly, message);

    return success; 
};
```

My current idea is to do something similar to the following:

```
public class Log
{
    string to = "me@me.com",
        from = "system@me.com",
        subject = "Error occured";

    public void Write( string executingAssembly, string message, bool sendEmail )
    {
        System.Diagnostic.EventLog.WriteEntry( executingAssembly, message);

        if( sendEmail )
            SendEmail( to, from, subject, message );
    }

    private void SendEmail( to, from, subject, message )
    {
        // Details to send email.
    }
}
```

Question: 
How could I improve the maintainability of logging errors and sending notifications within my application?

Answer (score 6):

Consider using a Logging and Log Manager program for example [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). You can then write a set of business rules for logging in a nlog.config (or application.config) file which specifies different locations to log to (targets) and you can specify what you want logged for each (depending on severity and class).

**Taken from the NLog Website**

Some NLog supported targets

- Files – single file or multiple, with automatic file naming and archival
- Event Log – local or remote
- Database – store your logs in databases supported by .NET
- Network – using TCP, UDP, SOAP, MSMQ protocols
- Command-line console – including color coding of messages
- E-mail – you can receive emails whenever application errors occur
- ASP.NET trace

Some Key Features of using NLog

- Very easy to configure, both through configuration file and programmatically
- Easy-to-use logger pattern known from log4xxx
- Advanced routing using buffering, asynchronous logging, load balancing, failover, and more
- Cross-platform support: .NET Framework, .NET Compact Framework and Mono (on Windows and Unix)

Comment: NLog supports many logging targets out of the box, including file and email.  It handles things like log file rotation and allows for extensive customization if needed.

Answer (score 1):

A few remarks :

Your log class should be a static class.
You should try/catch all error handling code, since the last thing error management should do... is to cause an error !
You could use an enum to list major error types and/or another one for severity / ...
I prefer log errors into a small text file in same folder as App. Easier to handle and the customer can send it with mail (i don't like the idea of application sending data by mail, you should check your customers/users are ok with this.).
You can get the executing assembly or other information from Reflection.
You might also get other valuable information from StackTrace (i do write the Stacktrace in my error logs, saved me quite some time).
You should caught also the unhandled exception at the Application level. 
Please describe a few more errors for more specific answer.

Comment: I agree with the sending the message via mail.  I should have mentioned that this is an automated task so I don't actually 'watch it' and want to know if anything bugs out.  The messages will go to me/dev team.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Enterprise Library has two very nice blocks, the [Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569%28v=pandp.50%29) and the [Exception Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664698%28v=pandp.50%29)

It's a policy based system that allows you to define different policies in your .config file. With the policies in place and some exception handlers, you can write your catch blocks like:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  if(HandleException("My Datalayer Policy", ex)) throw;
}
```

Exception Policies can be configured to bubble the event, or not.  Very nice library.

The Logging block also uses "policies" from the .config which are called categories.  For example, if I want to log some messages, but others I wanted to also email, I would use two categories and two listeners, one for logging the event and one for emailing the details of the event.  If the email category is not specified, for example when Sucess is true, then only a logging event occurs.  When success is false, the "Email" category is applied and both listeners fire.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that not successful task execution is something exceptional (otherwise you will send a lot of emails to someone). Thus, throw an exception when task fails (you can also provide additional details about why task failed). Here is some code with usage of [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/):

```
private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

public bool MethodFoo() 
{
   try
   {
       new Task().Execute();
       _logger.Info("Task executed successfully");
       return true;           
   }
   catch(YourCustomException ex)
   {
       _logger.ErrorException("Cannot execute task", ex);
       return false;
   }
}
```

The only thing left is NLog configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
    <targets>
        <target name="eventLog" xsi:type="EventLog" 
                log="Application" source="Your Source" machineName="."
                layout="${longdate}|${level}|${callsite:methodName=true}${message}" />
        <target name="email" xsi:type="Mail" 
                subject="Error occured"
                to="me@me.com"
                from="system@me.com"
                smtpServer="127.0.0.1"
                smtpPort="25"
                body="${longdate}|${message}" />  
    </targets> 
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="eventLog" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="email" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

You need two targets - one for writing informational and error messages to Event Log, and second to send error notification by email. Also I created two rules - all messages of level Info and above will be sent to Event Log, but Error and Fatal messages will be sent by email.

BTW with callsite layout renderer `${callsite:methodName=true}` method name will be inserted to log message. Thus you don't need to specify it in code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abstract the logging abstractions that others here have suggested, you can use [Commons Logging](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging). Yes, that's two layers of indirection, but there are situations where it could be useful.

You can install the NuGet package and then use it in your code like this:

```
// obtain logger instance
ILog log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

// log something
log.Info("Some Debug Log Output");
```

Then configure the commons logging library to use NLog like this:

```
<common>
  <logging>
    <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog20">
      <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
    </factoryAdapter>
  </logging>
</common>
```

Then you can configure NLog. @Sergey Berezovskiy's answer has an example of this.

The point being, the [Commons Logging](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging) library doesn't make you choose between NLog or log4net or Logging Application Block or whatever else. You can switch the back-end to whatever you want. This can be useful if you're writing a dll or something that might be hosted in a variety of project types. Of course it can also be a useless extra layer of indirection. It just depends what you're doing.